# Quantum beam-splitter matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, linear-algebra

I have seen the matrix for the action on a quantum beam splitter described in one of two ways:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
t_1 & r_2 \\
r_1 & t_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
(this appears in [Quantum Optics by Girish Agarwal page 104](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7KKw_XIYaioC&printsec=frontcover&dq=quantum%20optics%20by%20girish%20s%20agarwal%20page%20104&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAWoVChMIja7m0LKKxgIVhW4UCh0yXQBl#v=snippet&q=The%20unitary%20requirement&f=false))

And also like this: 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
r_1 & t_2 \\
t_1 & r_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
(this appears in this http://physics.gu.se/~ostlund/kvant/ajpbs02-2.pdf)

Both of these sources then go onto say that for a 50:50 beam splitter the matrix $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 &i\\
i & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Is one of the sources wrong or are we free to chose which coefficient (i.e. the tranmission or reflection) we include the $i$ with, without it affecting the results?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, this particular definition tacitly assumes that the beamsplitter's transfer matrix is *invariant with respect to a swap in the roles of the ports*, which is why you swap the roles of reflexion and transmission, yet get the same result. This seemingly odd assumption simply arises from an assumption that the beamsplitter has a certain spatial symmetry.

To understand this, let's look at the general case and understand that there's actually a great deal of leeway in specifying a beamsplitter, even a lossless 50:50 one. Look up your favorite reference to find a general expression for a general $2\times 2$ unitary matrix $U$; one possibility is:

$$U = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a&b\\-b^\ast\,e^{i\,\varphi}&a^\ast\,e^{i\,\varphi}\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i\,\alpha}\,\cos\theta&e^{i\,\beta}\,\sin\theta\\-e^{i\,(\varphi-\beta)}\,\sin\theta&e^{i\,(\varphi-\alpha)}\,\cos\theta\end{array}\right)$$

where $a,\,b\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$. So, equivalently, our general unitary matrix can be specified by putting $a=e^{i\,\alpha}\cos\theta$ and $b = e^{i\,\beta}\,\sin\theta$ for $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. In general, therefore, a unitary matrix, once its splitting ratio has been specified by fixing $\theta$, has *three* real parameters $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\varphi$ that can be arbitrarily chosen. Now, an even power splitting condition is simply the condition that $\theta \in \left\{\frac{\pi}{4}+2\,k_1\,\pi,\,\frac{3\,\pi}{4}+2\,k_2\,\pi,\,\frac{5\,\pi}{4}+2\,k_3\,\pi,\,\frac{7\,\pi}{4}+2\,k_4\,\pi \right\}$ where $k_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. The phase factors $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\varphi$ are varied by choosing different reference points as "ports" where the phase of the wave is defined. We can arbitrarily slide a "port" along its beam; as long as we stick with a position during a calculation, any position in the beam will do.

The stated matrices actually arise from the further condition that the beamsplitter is symmetric *and* that the reference ports are symmetrically placed with respect to the beamsplitter. That is, the transfer matrix must be *invariant* under the similarity transformation defined by $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$, which swaps the roles of transmission and reflexion ports. So we get:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i\,\alpha}\,\cos\theta&e^{i\,\beta}\,\sin\theta\\-e^{i\,(\varphi-\beta)}\,\sin\theta&e^{i\,(\varphi-\alpha)}\,\cos\theta\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i\,\alpha}\,\cos\theta&e^{i\,\beta}\,\sin\theta\\-e^{i\,(\varphi-\beta)}\,\sin\theta&e^{i\,(\varphi-\alpha)}\,\cos\theta\end{array}\right)$$

or:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i\,\alpha}\,\cos\theta&e^{i\,\beta}\,\sin\theta\\-e^{i\,(\varphi-\beta)}\,\sin\theta&-e^{i\,(\varphi-\alpha)}\,\cos\theta\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}e^{i\,(\varphi-\alpha)}\,\cos\theta&-e^{i\,(\varphi-\beta)}\,\sin\theta\\e^{i\,\beta}\,\sin\theta& e^{i\,\alpha}\,\cos\theta\end{array}\right)$$

so that now we must have $\alpha = \frac{\varphi}{2}\mod 2\,\pi$ and $\beta = \frac{\varphi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\mod 2\,\pi$ so that:

$$U = e^{i\frac{\varphi}{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta&i\,\sin\theta\\i\,\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{array}\right)$$

and the most convenient choice is $\phi=0$. We can vary $\phi$ because we can still shift the reference ports, as long as we do so symmetrically.

Comment: I've always found the beam-splitter derivation math to be confusing, so thanks for the explantion. I have some questions:  Does theta represent a parameter that can be "swept" through to obtain all the possible unitary matrices for a beam splitter? So does this include the "unbalanced beamsplitter" cases? If so, then isn't this swapping transmission-reflection condition not valid?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it in this case is a bit of semantics. In an ideal beam-splitter there is really no "true" reflection. Rather the beam is split into two output directions. Which one of the two directions you call transmitted and deflected is a matter of taste.

Naively I would say the example with transition $t$ on the diagonal looks more natural. In this case the identity matrix just means that light is transmitted, as if the beam splitter was not present.